# HTML form which gives feedback immediately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

I have been asked to produce a 'workbook' in the form of a website. At the end of the workbook the user will be asked set of specific questions where he/she will answer yes/no - this will be in the form of radio buttons.

example: "Did you understand section 1?" ..... YES/NO

When the user has finished answering these questions a lightbox page should appear to tell them to go back to specific points in the website.

I have looked around and can't find any examples so it's quite hard to explain. does anybody know how this can be done? I appreciate any advice

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a place where people just write all the code for you

Comment: I was not asking for the code, sorry if that's how it came across. I was asking how it can be done - so what language I would have to learn / where would I have to go learn to do this. I am new to this field. Thanks @laurens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if all questions are answered:

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes" />
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="no" />
</div>
<div class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes" />
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="no" />
</div>
<div class="question">
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="yes" />
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="no" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(":radio").change(function() {
    if (!$('.question:not(:has(:radio:checked))').length) {
        alert("all questions are filled in, add code to show colorbox/lightbox/bootstrap modal here")
    }
})
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgtcenj8/1/). I would suggest to use [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to create the overlay popup. Another nice one is to use [bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

EDIT: updates [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgtcenj8/2/) now working with bootstrap modal!

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on this and show you what I have produced.

Comment: See my updated jsfiddle for an implementation with bootstrap modal

Comment: Hi @DavidPaulAnthony if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.